# How to make this onclick go to a dynamic url?

Tags: html, angular

So I have an onclick that directs to a linkedin page here:

```
<li id="toHover" onclick=" window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/in/jvanderkooi/?originalSubdomain=nl','_blank')" class="list-inline-item"><a naam="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-naam="LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
```

This works great, it opens a new window with the provided url and leaves the other one open. However, I dont want to use this in-build url but want this element to get the url attribute of a certain user. Something like this:

```
<li id="toHover" onclick="window.open(user.linkedinURL, 'new_window')" 
class="list-inline-item"><a naam="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-naam="LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
```

When i do this, a new window opens up the root of my web app. Im currently running this on localhost only so I get to http://localhost:8080 where my app is running instead of the linkedin page url provided.

I tried doing this a bunch of different ways but just can't seem to get it to work. What am I missing here?

Edit:
Here is the rest of the div that i am looping through for this in case it clears things up.

```
<div class="container" id="main-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div *ngFor= "let user of users" class ="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="card m-b-30">
                        <div class="card-body row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <!-- <a href=""><img src="{{user?.imageUrl}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-60"></a> -->
                                <a href=""><img src="{{user?.photo}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-60"></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6 card-naam align-self-center mb-0">
                                <h5>{{user.name}}</h5>
                                <p class="m-0">{{user.function}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>{{user.email}} <a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Nummer: {{user.phoneNumber}}</li>
                            <li *ngIf="user.admin"  class="list-group-item"><i ></i>Admin</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="float-right btn-group btn-group-sm">
                                <a (click)="onOpenModal(user, 'edit')" class="btn btn-primary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-naam="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
                                <a (click)="onOpenModal(user, 'delete')" class="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-naam="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="social-links list-inline mb-0">
                                <style>
                                    #toHover{
                                        cursor: pointer;}
                                </style>
                 <li id="toHover" onclick="window.open(user.linkedinURL, 'new_window')" 
class="list-inline-item"><a naam="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" 
class="tooltips" data-original-naam="LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to anchor `a` element inside the `li`.

Use the below

`<li id="toHover" onclick="window.open(user.linkedinURL, 'new_window')" ></li>`
If you need to use `a` tag, then you can try this and specify target blank

```
<li id="toHover"   
class="list-inline-item"><a naam="" target="_blank" href="user.linkedinURL" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-naam="LinkedIn"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion ends up wih a clickable that deosnt do anything when clicked, does not even open up a new tab for me.

your second suggestion ends up the same as what i tried to do. it opens a new tab to localhost, not the url provided.

Comment: can you put alert in onclick="alert(user.linkedinURL);window.open(user.linkedinURL, 'new_window');" and show me output pls. I need to know how user object is passed.

Comment: creating an alert makes the button not do anything, no alert, no new tab.

Comment: try this `(click)="openNewWindow(user.linkedinURL)" ` and in ur ts, `openNewWindow(url1){
    window.open(url1);
  }` . YOu should always look in console for any errors.

Comment: using this (click) did the trick. Now its working as I wanted it to. Thanks a bunch for the help! Do you know why it wasn't possible to just do this from html directly?

Comment: onclick is html attribute event binding where as (click) is angular way of event binding. In onclick you cant use angular objects like user.linkedURL as you used.

Answer (score 0):

Here your solution even with `.focus()` to make it active:

```js
document.querySelector('.open-url').addEventListener('click', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank').focus();
});
```

```html
<li id="toHover" class="list-inline-item">
    <a href="https://google.com" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips open-url" data-original-naam="LinkedIn">Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Don't forget to put https or http to prevent opening in your local host ^_^

Comment: I do have a complete and valid url stored, with http. Unfortunately putting it into a function ends up doing nothing, does not even open a new tab for some reason.

Comment: @Gijs25 in this case browser blocking now popup window. I have made a changes to my answer.